# How to handle Angular 5 select binding to a null value

Tags: angular5, angular-forms

I have a reactive form with a select

```
<select [(ngModel)]="user.positionId" name="positionId" class="custom-select form-control form-control-sm" required
        formControlName="positionId"
        [ngClass]="{
        'is-invalid': positionId.invalid && (positionId.dirty || positionId.touched),
        'is-valid': positionId.valid && (positionId.dirty || positionId.touched)
        }">         
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let position of user.positionSelectList" value="{{position.value}}">
        {{position.text}}
    </option>
</select>
```

It gets passed positionId which is a nullable number

```
export class User{
    id: string;
    userName: string;
    positionId?: number;
}
```

The above works when I pass a number value as positionId.

However when it gets passed a null value then the default option of "--Select--" is not selected but an additional blank option appears above it.

What I have tried.

```
 <option value=null>--Select--</option>
```

and

```
 <option value=udefined>--Select--</option>
```

but this gives the same result of "--Select--" not selected

I do not wish to set hardcoded  number values a fixed number e.g. -1 as I need the required validation to kick in which requires a blank value if not selected.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried using `ngValue`?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="user.positionId" name="positionId" class="custom-select form-control form-control-sm" required
        formControlName="positionId"
        [ngClass]="{
        'is-invalid': positionId.invalid && (positionId.dirty || positionId.touched),
        'is-valid': positionId.valid && (positionId.dirty || positionId.touched)
        }">         
    <option [ngValue]="null">--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let position of user.positionSelectList" value="{{position.value}}">
        {{position.text}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: is bad practice to mix Template Driven and Reactive Form